# Is the "link" URL enough to uniquely identify an "inbox_item"?

Tags: support, api-v2

I've been looking at the documentation on the [`inbox_item`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) type, and I was wondering what is the correct way to uniquely identify an inbox_item?

Is the "link" URL enough to uniquely identify an "inbox_item"? Is it ever the case that two links will point to the same notification event?

What happens when questions are migrated to new sites? Does the link change in this case too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`link` is the best way to distinguish between items.  No two items should have the same link, and inbox items aren't updated after they are created; they're snapshots of activity more than references to it.

Comment: OK, that clears up a lot of confusion... my next question was going to be are inbox items ever change once they're created. Thanks!